# Two ray ground reflection model to predict antenna performance over conducting ground

Tags: antennas, method-of-images

I have an antenna that is placed at a certain height over conducting ground plane. If it's measured, I could imagine ripples in a farfield pattern owing to reflection from the ground. Is it correct to use two-ray ground reflection models to predict the complexity of interference patterns (maxima/minima) in the far field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as a second step in a link budget analysis, it is a standard procedure to continue with a two-ray model. To be useful and not just provide crude estimates, you need to know the ground reflectivity to incident polarization, vegetation, dry/wet soil, snow, rain, humidity, etc. At your leisure, check out Nathanson: Radar Design Principles (chapter 7),  it is full of this stuff.